# parent-element does not scale with styled links

Tags: html, css, styling

[Example @JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qysnr/)

Why does the grey box wrapping the blue boxes *not* scale with them? I have tried many different combinations of attributes for the elements, but I cannot get it to work properly.

The effect is not bad actually, but not what I want. An explanation of why this happens would be helpful. Thanks in advance! :)

PS: I am on Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1

---

[image]

Comment: For clarification, do you want the gray bar to only expand wide enough to contain the blue links, or do you want to blue links to expand to fill the space within the gray bar?

Comment: @PJMcCormick Isn't it kind of obvious, even just by looking at the CSS? I've added padding to the `a` elements which makes them bigger. But the grey box kept its size.

Comment: If it was completely obvious, I wouldn't have asked. I wanted to make sure I understood what you trying to achieve before I suggested something that may not have been relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` elements have their display property set to `inline`. This essentially means that they are treated as text and thus any 'block' type properties applied to them will not work as you would expect them to as you would if it was say, a div.

Learning about the display property is a massive part of CSS, but for this example you want the links to be inline but also a block so you would use:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

Now the outer div will take into account the size of the `inline-block` elements whereas before it would not as it was treating your links as if they were just text.

Comment: @NiklasR You'll probably want to do further reading but I hope it was a good start anyway =)